# Apache camel restlet not working when integrated with servlet engine

Tags: apache-camel, restlet-2.0

i Am trying to integrate restlet with servlet engine so that i do not spawn a new server process.

I have made the following configuration in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-rs</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.Component</param-name>
            <param-value>RestletComponent</param-value>
        </init-param>



        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-rs</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In my spring applicationContext.xml i have the below entries,

```
 <bean name = "RestletComponent" id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />
    <bean name = "RestletComponentService" id="RestletComponentService" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="RestletComponent" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route id = "RS_getdata">
            <from uri="restlet:/getData?restletMethod=POST" />
</camelContext>
```

But when i try to invoke the restful service, i am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'name' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.transformedBeanName(BeanFactoryUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet.createApplication(SpringServerServlet.java:77)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getApplication(ServerServlet.java:802)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createServer(ServerServlet.java:538)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getServer(ServerServlet.java:945)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your bean the same name as the component name, for Camel to use it, eg:

```
<bean name = "RestletComponent" id="RestletComponent"
```

should be

```
<bean name = "restlet" id="restlet"
```